# canvas (about) 5px line -- add bevel effect to make it 3D -- any ideas? (Sample of desired final effect included)

Tags: image-processing, canvas, bevelled

I want to draw (for instance) a line on HTML5 canvas. Then I want to add an image bevel effect to that line. So it looks 3D, like a piece of string sitting on the canvas.
Has anyone seen an image processing effect that can do something along that line?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do that kind of drawing is to draw step by step the curve, and apply at each step a texture perpendicular to the local tangent.

But you seem to want another feature : be able to 'twist' the texture depending on the part of the curve.  Here there are so mant options to parameterize this i can't guess how you'll store/interpolate the twist of the texture. So below i just had the texture 'turn' with t, the parameter of the bezier curve.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/YPKV9/

Example : Image showing a texture applied to the curve, and below the same curve with the same texture that turns along with the curve.

[image]

```
//  ----------------------------------------------
//  Draw bezier curve filled with 
//    with txCv used as perpendicular texture 
//    signature : drawTexturedBezier ( txCv, a, b, c, d, twisted )
//    a,b,c,d are control points, twisted means
//      do we have to twist the curve.
//          Width of the bezier is == to txCv.width/2 
//          when the draw resolution is tx.height (lower = nicer+slower, 3 seems fine )
//  ----------------------------------------------
function drawTexturedBezier() {
    // build onnly once local vars
    var pt = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var tg = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var lastPt = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    drawTexturedBezier = function (txCv, a, b, c, d, twisted) {
        var lineHeight = txCv.height;
        var t = 0;
        var incr = 1 / 1000;
        var pointCount = 0;
        pt.x = a.x;
        pt.y = a.y;
        var thisCoordsForT = coordsForT.bind(null, a, b, c, d);
        var thisTgtForT = tangentForT.bind(null, a, b, c, d);
        // scan the bezier curve by increment of lineHeight distance
        //  on the curve.
        do {
            // update last point
            lastPt.x = pt.x;
            lastPt.y = pt.y;
            // seek next point far enough from previous point
            // just compute one point ahead
            //   using average estimate for t of '1 point ahead'
            thisCoordsForT(t + incr, pt);
            var dx = pt.x - lastPt.x;
            dx *= dx;
            var dy = pt.y - lastPt.y;
            dy *= dy;
            // compute distance to previous point
            var dist = Math.sqrt(dx + dy);
            // compute required t increment
            // considering curve is locally linear
            //  0.92 compensates for the error.
            var tIncrement = 0.92 * incr * (lineHeight / dist);
            t += tIncrement;
            // compute point
            thisCoordsForT(t, pt);
            pointCount++;
            // update regular increment with local one 
            incr = 0.2 * incr + 0.8 * tIncrement;
            // compute tangent for current point
            thisTgtForT(t, tg);
            // draw with perpendicular texture
            drawTexturedLine(txCv, pt, tg, t, twisted);
        } while (t < 1);
    };
    return drawTexturedBezier.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

With

```
// draws a rect centered on pt, for a curve having tg as local tangent
//     having size of : txCv.width/2 X txCv.height
//      using the txCv horizontal pattern as pattern.
function drawTexturedLine(txCv, pt, tg, t, twisted) {
    var lineWidth = txCv.width / 2;
    var lineHeight = txCv.height;
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI + Math.atan2(-tg.x, tg.y));
    var twistFactor = 0;
    if (twisted) {
        twistFactor = (2 * t + animating * Date.now() / 2000) % 1;
    }
    context.drawImage(txCv,
    twistFactor * lineWidth, 0, lineWidth, lineHeight, -0.5 * lineWidth, -0.5 * lineHeight, lineWidth, lineHeight);
    context.restore();
}
```

Comment: OMG I didn't know you could twist textures. This is perfect.

Comment: Actually I don't care so much about the twisting that was just part of the original effect in Photoshop, which assumes the light source is static, for instance, to the 'top right', which causes the shadow always on the bottom left. But in reality, I don't care, as long as I can create the effect.

Comment: You're welcome ! Notice that if you don't use the twist you can simplify a bit the code and use a (lineHeight X lineWidth) texture. (If you use the twist you must replicate the texture horizontally into a (2*lineHeight X lineWidth texture) to be able to loop). Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

A 3 pixel wide line is too thin to achieve a decent bevel effect.

Instead, try using canvas's shadowing capabilities to give a 3d effect to your line.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/djvQV/

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(150,50);
ctx.shadowColor="black";
ctx.shadowBlur=5;
ctx.shadowOffsetY=3;
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You're right, 3px is too little. I wasn't thinking. Added sample image above, using Photoshop. This is exactly what I'm looking to achieve...

Comment: Hmmm...kind of a smudge tool effect.  You might still experiment with multiple bezierCurveTo paths with a shadowBlur on some of the curves on the path.

Comment: Do you know I like that I'm suprised I didn't think of it, that's not bad.